# Por que el error en sintaxis (SQL server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server

la siguente consulta:

```
DECLARE @ntp int,
@jugador varchar (max)= 'Hola',
@Player varchar (max)

SET @Jugador = @Player



EXEC    @ntp = [PS_GameDefs].[dbo].[Command]
        @serviceName = N'ps_game',
        @cmmd = N'/ntplayer '+@Player+' '+ ' '+'Has ganado'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @ntp

GO
```

me arroja el siquiente error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

se nota que es el simbolo de "+" el detalle que creo la consulta esta bien pero no me explico ¿por que el error?

Comment: ¿Qué representa la `N` tanto aquí: `N'ps_game'` como aquí: `N'/ntplayer '`? no tengo mucho dominio de SQL Server, por eso pregunto. ¿Por qué no eres coherente con las variables: declaras `@jugador varchar (max)= 'Hola'` y luego seteas: `SET @Jugador = @Player`, o sea, `j` en una parte y `J` en otra  ¿?

Comment: No, no puedes hacer esto `@cmmd = N'/ntplayer '+@Player+' '+ ' '+'Has ganado'`, no puedes concatenar los datos, porque en la asignación del parámetro el motor no evalúa nada. Te recomiendo, crea primero una variable `@cmmd`, la completas como lo estas haciendo ahora y la asignación del parámetro la haces como `@cmmd  = @cmmd`

Comment: La primera respuesta eso hice arriba se lee claro y la segunda respuesta no la comprendi

Comment: No comprendí tu comentario. ¿Te diste cuenta que tienes en una parte `jugador` con minúscula y en otra parte `Jugador` con mayúscula. No sé si esto afecte, pero al menos no eres coherente haciendo eso.

Comment: Lo que quiere decir Patricio es que no puedes pasarle como parámetro al procedimiento almacenado la formulación en el parámetro @cmmd. Debes, como el bien indica, hacer dicha formulación antes de ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado y luego si asignar dicha variable al parámetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es por que no puedes hacer esto:

```
EXEC    ....
        @cmmd = N'/ntplayer '+@Player+' '+ ' '+'Has ganado'
```

No hay evaluación a nivel de parámetros de un SP, tienes que pasar el parámetro ya evaluado o construido. Por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @cmmd NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Construímos el parámetro
SET @cmmd = N'/ntplayer '+@Player+' '+ ' '+'Has ganado'

EXEC    @ntp = [PS_GameDefs].[dbo].[Command]
        @serviceName = N'ps_game',
        @cmmd = @cmmd
```